# How to elegantly copy a portion of an array into or inject into another array

Tags: arrays, go, insert

I have the following code which works but the point here is that I want to inject or insert one array of arbitrary length into another statically sized  array extending its length:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    ffmpegArguments := []string{
        "-y",
        "-i", "invideo",
        // ffmpegAudioArguments...,
        "-c:v", "copy",
        "-strict", "experimental",
        "outvideo",
    }

    var outputArguments [12]string
    copy(outputArguments[0:3], ffmpegArguments[0:3])
    copy(outputArguments[3:7], []string{"-i", "inaudio", "-c:a", "aac"})
    copy(outputArguments[7:12], ffmpegArguments[3:8])

    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", ffmpegArguments)
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", outputArguments)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/peQXkOpheK4

Comment: What is not working in your code?

Comment: You cannot change the length of an array, it's fixed at compile time. What you want is a [slice](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/7).

Comment: @Volker This code is working but I would like to know how to put in arbitrary length of arrays between the 3rd argument and the 7th argument as you can see demonstrated (but hard-coded)

Comment: The pseudocode would look something like this - I do realize arrays are fixed in length - what is a golang way of resizing and slicing the arrays - that or or what library would accomplish this for b when b can be any length:

a := []string{"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"}
b := []string{"a", "b"}
a = a.inject(3, b)           // => 1,2,3,a,b,4,5,6,7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up modifying the answer from @Alirus by making a *copy* of the array first because it appears that the first assignment points to the haystack array and subsequent steps modify the `haystack` slice:

```js
// arrayInject is a helper function written by Alirus on StackOverflow in my
// inquiry to find a way to inject one array into another _elegantly_:
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/53647212/776896
func arrayInject(haystack, pile []string, at int) (result []string) {
 result = make([]string, len(haystack[:at]))
 copy(result, haystack[:at])
 result = append(result, pile...)
 result = append(result, haystack[at:]...)

 return result
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Talking about *elegant* is somewhat opinionated, but one may come up with [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) principle. BTW, you can use a simpler approach with *slices* which does not require you to guess the output array size:

```
func inject(haystack, pile []string, at int) []string {
    result := haystack[:at]
    result = append(result, pile...)
    result = append(result, haystack[at:]...)

    return result
}
```

And, rewrite your code as follows:

```
ffmpegArguments := []string{
    "-y",
    "-i", "invideo",
    "-c:v", "copy",
    "-strict", "experimental",
    "outvideo",
}

outputArguments := inject(ffmpegArguments, []string{"-i", "inaudio", "-c:a", "aac"}, 3)

fmt.Printf("%#v\n", ffmpegArguments)
fmt.Printf("%#v\n", outputArguments)
```

Comment: I love it, I think that does seem elegant in that you are operating on the same array each step (result) and building that array - thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Since you're **appending** to the output I recommend this (simple and **consistent**) and set the max capacity:

```
out := make([]string, 0, 12)
out = append(out, in[0:3]...)
out = append(out, []string{"-i", "inaudio", "-c:a", "aac"}...)
out = append(out, in[3:8]...)
```

see:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    in := []string{
        "-y",
        "-i", "invideo",
        // ffmpegAudioArguments...,
        "-c:v", "copy",
        "-strict", "experimental",
        "outvideo",
    }

    out := make([]string, 0, 12)
    out = append(out, in[0:3]...)
    out = append(out, []string{"-i", "inaudio", "-c:a", "aac"}...)
    out = append(out, in[3:8]...)

    fmt.Println(in)
    fmt.Println(out)
}
```

result:

```
[-y -i invideo -c:v copy -strict experimental outvideo]
[-y -i invideo -i inaudio -c:a aac -c:v copy -strict experimental outvideo]
```